# OS X keeps crashing while compiling

Tags: snow-leopard, xcode

I have a fresh install of Snow Leopard on a 32bit Core Duo.

Ever since I installed Snow Leopard, I have random crashes when compiling:
i.e. - during `brew install imagemagick`. While brew installed dependencies (tiff and little-cms) it finished just fine, but when it went to compile imagemagick itself, it crashes.

During `make install` for imagemagick, the system fans just spin up then my computer shuts down.

I've looked at mkmf.log and CrashReporter, but nothing is in them about this install.

I'm using Xcode is 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3.

Any other log files I can view?  Any ideas?

---

EDIT - I noticed that this was happening during compiling only.  Also noticed that fans started to spin up before crashes but never got a chance to spin to max speed.  I guess somewhere along the way, either one of my fans went out, or something of the sort.

So I did the following:

I downloaded and installed [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/index.html), then [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?p=134).

I set the Higher RPM in smcFanControl to max.  Right before I started to install apps which needed compiling like imagemagick I turned smcFanControl to max and monitored CPU temp.  So far I've been able to install without crashes, but now I know I need to be replacing my mac soon.

Comment: This seems to happen when there's "high CPU" activity, can you confirm that it happens like that? It might point towards some sort of overheat or memory problem.

Comment: Yes.  During reinstall of xcode (originally thought this was problem), CPU temp spiked to 109 deg C before fans kicked in, but then crashed when temp hit 117.  This has been happening to me since installing Snow.  Guess a fan, temp sensor or something went bad.  Can confirm that after forcing fans on when temp goes above 70 C, I can install without a prob.

Comment: BTW - Also had to keep fans running after install cause md5 / Indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a hardware error. Heat or memory related issues?

You should try the hardware test using your Install CD.

Comment: The question was "any ideas?", so... yes, this is an answer. Anyway, it was more helpful than your comment... ;)

Comment: No, it's not an answer. It doesn't directly answer the question. It would be much better as a comment. Maybe this? Maybe that? That's a comment.

Comment: This did help me find "my" problem.  See edit of question and comments below.

Answer (score 0):

The most serious issue here is your shut down. We need to see what the cause of this is.

1. Open Console: Finder -> Go -> Utilities -> Console
2. In Console: Files -> system.log
3. Search for: "Previous Shutdown Cause"

Please let us know what this is.

Comment: Since its been a couple of days, did search in "All Messages".  All Previous Shutdown Cause have been 0 or 3.  Did update question.